# Alternative codeing instead of "if else" logic for Android

Tags: android

I create a script that displays the results depending on the selected options.

I need:  A, B, C, D (0,1,-1)

```
int A = 0;
int B = 0;
int C = 0;
int D = 0;
```

Ansver will be one of 16 combination.

```
if A = 1 = A1;
if A = -1 = A2;
if B = 1 = B1;
if B = -1 B2;
if C = 1 = C1;
If C = -1 = C2;
If D = 1 = D1;
if D = -1 = D1;

A1;B1;C1;D1 = Nr1
A1;B1;C1;D2 = Nr2
A1;B1;C2;D1 = Nr3
A1;B1;C2;D2 = Nr4
A1;B2;C1;D1 = Nr5
A1;B2;C1;D2 = Nr6
A1;B2;C2;D1 = Nr7
A1;B2;C2;D2 = Nr8
A2;B1;C1;D1 = Nr9
A2;B1;C1;D2 = Nr10
A2;B1;C2;D1 = Nr11
A2;B1;C2;D2 = Nr12
A2;B2;C1;D1 = Nr13
A2;B2;C1;D2 = Nr14
A2;B2;C2;D1 = Nr15
A2;B2;C2;D2 = Nr16
```

I want to show the potential variants.
When you press the combination of: `A1, B1 = "Nr1,Nr2,Nr3,Nr4"`
When you press the combination of: `A1, D1 = "Nr1,Nr3,Nr5,Nr7"`
Later will be more variables `E`, `F`, `G`, `H` .... etc. But the answers will only 16th

**What could be the logic, I'm a little stuck?**

`If / Else` seems to be too long.

Example if/else:

```
    if (A == 1) {
        if (B == 1) {
            if (C == 1) {
                if (D == 1) {
                    scoreTeamA = "Nr1"; //A1,B1,C1,D1
                } else if (D == -1) {
                    scoreTeamA = "Nr2"; //A1,B1,C1,D2
                } else scoreTeamA = "Nr1, Nr2"; //A1,B1,C1
            } else if (B == 1) {
                if (D == 1) {
                    scoreTeamA = "Nr3"; //A1,B1,C1,D1
                } else if (D == -1) {
                    scoreTeamA = "Nr4"; //A1,B1,C1,D2
                } else scoreTeamA = "Nr3,Nr4"; //A1,B1,C2
            } else scoreTeamA = "Nr1,Nr2,Nr3,Nr4"; //A1,B1
        } else if (B == -1) {
            scoreTeamA = "Nr5,Nr6,Nr7,Nr8";//A1,B2
        } else
            scoreTeamA = "Nr1,Nr2,Nr3,Nr4,Nr5,Nr6,Nr7,Nr8"; //A1
    } else if (A == -1) { 
        scoreTeamA = "Nr9,Nr10,Nr11,Nr12,Nr13,Nr14,Nr15,Nr16"; //A2
    }
```

Comment: The logic depends on you, how you want your code to be.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the alternatives that come to mind:

1. A long chain of `if...else` statements.
2. `switch` statements. This won't be much better than `if...else`, though.
3. A data structure, such as a `Map`.
4. A custom class hierarchy. Often a `switch` statement can be replaced by polymorphism. This is highly dependent on the specifics of what you are really doing.

Comment: I do not understand what might have been then that code, if want to use a       `map`, understand that this is the best of the options.

Comment: @MārtiņšDoniņš I do not understand your comment

Comment: @Code-Apprentics I do not understand how to use the `map` for all of this. Existing code: [link](https://github.com/MartinsDonins/MDProject/blob/master/app/src/main/java/lv/digitalteam/android/socionicscalculator/MainActivity.java)
maybe you can share with an example. Otherwise, now all the time I find wrong examples.

Comment: @MārtiņšDoniņš I would create a class that holds A, B, C, and D to use as the key. The value is just what you put in scoreTeamA in your code here. You can hard code the creation of the map or read the data from a file. Once the map is created, create a key object and call get().

Answer (score 1):

For that you are using `switch-case`.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html